# How to scrape JSON file from url and print contents

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is the website I want to scrape: https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json

I have no idea how to scrape the JSON file from the URL and print out the contents.
I tried reading around, but the most I got was this code, which doesn't work when I run it:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = json.loads(r.content)
print(cont)
```

Comment: The code works fine when I run it. Can you describe what specifically is not working?

Comment: It shows that it's loading and freezes the entire screen, not letting me click or type anything in both the Shell and in my program. I tried waiting it out, but even after 20 minutes it still shows that it's loading

Comment: Code works fine for me - Python 3.

Answer (score 6):

Almost correct. Should be r.json(). Requests has a built in json parser.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
print(cont)
```

Also if you want to print the specific contents just iterate over it like you would any other json obj

```
for k in cont:
    if k['name'] == 'VapersCoin':
        do_something()
```

Comment: I tried this code but for some reason I still run into the problem where my development environment completely freezes, where I can't click or type anything into the shell or my program. My cursor indicates that the program is loading(?). I waited around 10 minutes but it didn't print out anything and was still stuck on that frozen mode.

Comment: Maybe you do not have enough memory to process this json. Can you tell me what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to iterate of the dictionary and print out some parts of it? I normally get freezes like this when I try to iterate huge files in memory. Like on which part of the code is it freezing? Is it on requests get? or is it on print part? Can you try to paste this code line by line in your console and tell me which part causes the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ran into string hell. Sometimes with Python3 you have to do encode() or decode() to convert byte strings to unicode strings.

In your sample code, if you change line 6 to

```
cont = json.loads(r.content.decode())
```

it will run. @PhilippeT 's solution is also fine, as the json() function seems to automatically return a unicode string.

Comment: I tried this code but for some reason I still run into the problem where my development environment completely freezes, where I can't click or type anything into the shell or my program. My cursor indicates that the program is loading(?). I waited around 10 minutes but it didn't print out anything and was still stuck on that frozen mode.

Comment: @j.doe: huh. Sometimes I get funky results trying to run straight from the IDE/editor. If you run from the terminal does it behave better. And as long as you're in the terminal can you ping the website?